# Understanding how to import a map.osm file into a postgres database.

Tags: postgresql, docker

I was just reading a tutorial **[HERE](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/osm2pgrouting.html)**.

I am assigned with the following task:

> The task is to create a Docker image that has PostgreSQL installed.
>   The PostgreSQL database should be PostGIS-enabled. The Docker image
>   should also allow quick and easy import of an .osm map data file into
>   the database. The database should contain a routable osm-based road
>   network which can be used to run simple default pgRouting queries
>   (shortest path, A star).

I know how to do the initial and final part of it but i am a bit confused about the following part:

> The Docker image should also allow quick and easy import of an .osm
>   map data file into the database.

How do i make this possible ? Dockerfile ? but still how ?

Comment: how would you do this on a Linux system? In a Dockerfile you have the RUN directive https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#run

Comment: @user2915097 , heres  what the guy told me `User builds the image with "map.osm" in the parameters to 'docker build'` , does that mean the map.osm file is added as a parameter , while running the build command ?

Comment: Well `docker build` may take a tag or a Dockerfile as a parameter, if you need to add a file, there is ADD or COPY inside a Dockerfile