# how to import a file as a parameter in Docker?

Tags: docker

I have been assigned the following task:

1. A Docker image with fresh Docker image (Ubuntu 14.04) or a PostgreSQL Docker image
2. User builds the image with "map.osm" in the parameters to 'docker build'.

I have completed the first part , but i am not sure what the second part really means.

I don't not quite understanding the 2nd part and how do i go about doing it ?

what does

> User builds the image with "map.osm" in the parameters to 'docker
>   build'

mean ?? i have this file with me, but i am not quite sure how to `builds the image with "map.osm" in the parameters to 'docker
build'` , Can somebody explain what this means to me ? or even better show me an example ?

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding how to import a map.osm file into a postgres database.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32443503/understanding-how-to-import-a-map-osm-file-into-a-postgres-database)

Comment: Your original question made more sense.

Comment: can you post your dockerfile so we can see what progress you've made? It's not clear if you installed postgres over ubuntu or used the postgres image.